# Can't run express server and Vue app concurrently

Tags: express, vue.js

My express server is set to run on port 8081. I start it up with `nodemon server/start.js`

My Vue app runs on port 8080. I run `nodemon build/dev-server.js` to start it.

The problem I have is if express server is running on 8081, I can't run Vue app. It just ends with this error:

`Starting dev server...
[1] Killed
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

I can start Vue if express is not running though.

I'm using NGINX btw.

Comment: Did you tried changing the port of express application?

Comment: Yes, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is a problem when you use `nodemon` to watch more than one file. You can follow this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/f9e0b83a447177ee6f66). You can try to run one file with `node`.

Answer (score 1):

As Tolsee mentioned, you can run both with a single command, just don't use nodemon for both files. Here is an example that is working for me with a Vue 2 app and an Express server:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js --hot | nodemon server.js", // this line
    "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  }
```

Hopefully that helps anyone that has run into this problem :)

Comment: Certainly helped me with a quick search/fix, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue once So, instead of using **nodemon** I suggest you to use **pm2**. Checkout this blog on using pm2 to run the Backend server and the frontend dev server simultaneously [**Simultaneously Running Express and Webpack Dev Server**](https://medium.com/dailyjs/vue-js-simultaneously-running-express-and-webpack-dev-server-292f4a7ed7a3) by **Henrik Fogelberg**

Comment: Thanks. Running on PM2, my Vue gets this error: App [vue] with id [1] and pid [15247], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGKILL]